# backbone.js and handlebars:string is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to run this code but this error appear: `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function` at line where is written : `var html = template(context);`
Does anybody know the reason?

**view**

```
define(["jQuery", "underscore", "Backbone", "Handlebars","models/person" ,"text!templates/userlistview.html"], 
function($, _, Backbone, Handlebars,Person, template) {

    var UserListView = Backbone.View.extend({

        template: Handlebars.compile(template),

        render: function() {
          var context = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model));
          console.log(context);
          var html = template(context);
          $(this.el).html(html);

          return this;
        }

     });

     return UserListView;
});
```

**router**

```
define(["jQuery", "underscore", "Backbone", "collections/usercollection", "models/person", "views/userlistview"], 
function($, _, Backbone, Usercollection, Person, UserListView) {

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            "": "list",
        },

        list: function() {
            this.utenti= new Person({name:"stefano",cognome:"magli"});
            this.page= new UserListView({model:this.utenti});

            this.page.render();
        }

    });

    return AppRouter;

});
```

Comment: just taking a guess here, as i can't try out your code right now: the line where the error occurs, try changing it to `var html = this.template(context)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `this`:

```
var html = this.template(context);
```

instead of:

```
var html = template(context);
```

`template` is `"text!templates/userlistview.html"`, while `this.template` is your compiled template.

**EDIT:**

this has nothing to do with your question, but you can replace `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model))` with `this.model.toJSON()`.

Comment: Ok now the error not appear, but on the browser nothing is rendered...is all empty.WHy?

Comment: check that `this.el` is a true element on the DOM. (you can use `this.$el` inseted of `$(this.el)`)

Comment: I've changed with  this.el.html(html) but now the error is :Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'html'

Comment: @StefanoMaglione this.$el.html , this.el is the DOM element

Comment: ok but the same problem:on the browser nothing is rendered.Maybe is the template??  <h1>{{cognome}} {{name}}</h1>?

Comment: @StefanoMaglione You have to attach your view to the DOM somewhere, for example `this.page.render(); $('body').append(this.page.$el);`

Comment: i've tried to view in the console the compiled template and it is perfect.I've added console.log(html) and the result is <h1>maglione stefano</h1>. So the problem is 100% at line:this.$el.html(html);

Comment: yeahh now is perfect..tnx very much